# Typescript complications with string unions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I'm trying to create a function that returns JSX depending on the name prop.
Here's my code:

```
function TabBarIcon(props: {
  name:
    | React.ComponentProps<typeof Ionicons>['name'] // 'key' | 'item' | 2000 more...
    | React.ComponentProps<typeof Feather>['name']; // 2000 different strings...
  color: string;
  type: 'Ionicons' | 'Feather';
}) {
  if (props.type === 'Ionicons')
    return <Ionicons size={30} style={{ marginBottom: -3 }} {...props} />;
  else if (props.type === 'Feather')
    return <Feather size={30} style={{ marginBottom: -3 }} {...props} />;
  else return <View />;
}
```

TypeScript throws an error because it can't be sure the `<Ionicons />` and `<Feather />` components contain name. I've attempted to workaround this with props.type, but TypeScript still throws an error. How can I return the correct component without the error? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the error message?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here to be a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N9AbJN), clearly demonstrates your issue. Or, if that is not possible, please consider providing a link to a properly configured web IDE project that demonstrates your issue.  This will help people work on an answer and increase the quality of answers you get.  Presumably the issue is that `props` is not in the form of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).

Comment: Here's a link, but it's giving a different error: https://snack.expo.io/GsNspaqKf. The error on my device is "Types of property 'name' are incompatible."

Comment: Looks like that IDE is expecting JS not TS code.  If I can't see the same issue you're seeing, it's hard for me to do anything with it.  Maybe you could either work on fixing that, or try to pare down the issue to something without external dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `Ionicons` has over 3,000 names while `Feather` has more like 300.  What happens if I call your component with `type="Feather"` and a name that only exists on `Ionicons`?

Your component is typed such that a `name` is a valid prop if it exists on *either* `Ionicons` or `Feather`.  But that's not good enough.  We need to know that the icon exists *on the chosen icon set*.

Defining the props as a union will make the error go away.

```
function TabBarIcon(props: { 
  color: string;
} & (
  {
    name: React.ComponentProps<typeof Ionicons>['name'];
    type: 'Ionicons';
  } | {
    name: React.ComponentProps<typeof Feather>['name'];
    type: 'Feather';
})) {
  if (props.type === 'Ionicons')
    return <Ionicons size={30} style={{ marginBottom: -3 }} {...props} />;
  else if (props.type === 'Feather')
    return <Feather size={30} style={{ marginBottom: -3 }} {...props} />;
  else return <View />;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! As a follow up, is it possible to avoid TS errors without including the 'type' prop?

Comment: What is your goal in doing that?  You don’t know which icon set without the type prop.

Comment: I'm hoping there's a way to check which icon to create by checking the name string and which set it falls under (assuming the sets are mutually exclusive)

Comment: I would see if that's even possible before you worry about the types.